# How to create editor script that will change the cube position on the y according to the terrain height changes with the paint brush?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a terrain and a cube.  in the editor I changed some places on the terrain height.
the cube stays on its original position.  what I want to do is when in the editor I'm changing the terrain areas height if there is an object on a specific place, I'm raising so the object will raise with the terrain. the object will keep on his relevant position.

I don't want the object to be on the top of the raised place but to move up with the terrain place the height changed.

[image: cube1]

[image: cube1]

so, the cube will change its height position according to the terrain specific area height if the cube is on that specific area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is literally a method named [SampleHeight(Vector3 position)](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Terrain.SampleHeight.html) in a Terrain class.
You could put almost exactly the code from sample into your script in Update() method. Don't forget to decorate the script with [ExecuteInEditMode] attribute so it can recieve the update event properly. Assuming you don't need that script in runtime, it would be smart to mark the component with [HideFlag](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/HideFlags.html) parameter upon creation.

Hope I helped you to get through. Please have a good day and stay awesome!